# Split channels from RGB array in C++ without OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, optimization, image-processing

I'm working in C++ with an array of unsigned char representing pixels in an image.     Each pixel has 3 channel (R,G,B).    The image is represented linearly,  sort of like

RGBRGBRGBRGB.....

How do I split each of the R,G and B, into separate arrays efficiently?

I tried:

```
  for(int pos = 0; pos < srcWidth * srcHeight; pos++) {
      int rgbPos = pos * 3;
      splitChannels[0][pos] = rgbSrcData[rgbPos];
      splitChannels[1][pos] = rgbSrcData[rgbPos + 1];
      splitChannels[2][pos] = rgbSrcData[rgbPos + 2];
  }
```

But this is surprisingly slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked how long just this loop takes to run, not including any other code? It doesn't look like it should be very slow.
Also, is there any reason you have to split them? Why not just loop through and use pos<srcWidth*srcHeight*3 and pos+=3 if you need a particular color?

Comment: Yes,  it is slow.    About 7 milliseconds for a 3MP image.   I have to split them in order to call another lib.

Comment: Well, 7*10^-3 seconds * 2 GigaHertz (for example) gets 14 million operations. 14 million ops sounds about right for a 3MP image. The right order of magnitude at the very least. Although, that's a very rough estimate and I don't have much experience in this, so I could be totally wrong, but it feels reasonable.

Comment: maybe there's a way to get it into SSE?   seems slow for moving bytes around.

Comment: The 2d destination array is set up in channel-major order, so a single pixel's three color components are separated in memory by srcWidth*srcHeight bytes, which might be reducing cache efficiency.  Try splitChannels[lotsa_pixels][3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt: load and store the bytes four by four. Byte scrambling will be tedious but possibly throughput will improve.

```
// Load 4 interleaved pixels
unsigned int RGB0= ((int*)rgbSrcData)[i];
unsigned int RGB1= ((int*)rgbSrcData)[i + 1];
unsigned int RGB2= ((int*)rgbSrcData)[i + 2];

// Rearrange and store 4 unpacked pixels
((int*)splitChannels[0])[j]= 
    (RGB0 & 0xFF) | (RGB0 >> 24) | (RGB1 & 0xFF0000) | ((RGB2 & 0xFF00) << 16);
((int*)splitChannels[1])[j]= 
    ((RGB0 & 0xFF00) >> 8) | (RGB1 & 0xFF) | (RGB1 >> 24) | (RGB2 & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
((int*)splitChannels[2])[j]= 
    ((RGB0 & 0xFF0000) >> 16) | (RGB1 & 0xFF00) | ((RGB2 & 0xFF) >> 16) | (RGB2 & 0xFF000000);
```

(CAUTION: not unchecked !) A shift-only version is also possible.

An SSE solution would be more complex (the stride 3 does not get along with powers of 2).

Comment: thanks, this is a great idea.   i tried this out and its about 10% faster.   it is difficult to get right with all the endianess.

Comment: Cool ! I was unsure this would be effective, given the big overhead. Even if the code is buggy, the timing measurements should be indicative. So it may be worth to scratch the code and spare a few cycles...

Comment: I actually had to drop it, there was improvement but not enough to make it workable.    It is very difficult to get it right.

Comment: If you want to achieve sheer performance, than the MMX/SSSE3 instructions *pshufb* and *punpckxxx* are your best friends. Load 3 x 8/16 bytes at a time and permute.

Answer (score 0):

A great technique to use to make it run faster is loop unwinding.
You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding

Comment: It didn't help.    I guess the compiler already does it when -O3 is enabled?

Comment: what was your unwinding factor ?

Comment: I didn't supply a factor,  just a flag?    -O3 does it I believe but not sure how much.